# Swagger Swashbuckle Polymorphism doesn't work with interface types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

With the code below I'm trying to mention alternative schemas; which share the same *interface*, as the type of the response.

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.UseOneOfForPolymorphism();
});

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
});
```

**Models**

```
public interface IOutput
{
    string Discriminator { get; }
}

public class OutputA : IOutput
{
    public string Discriminator => GetType().Name;

    public string PropA { get; set; }
}

public class OutputB : IOutput
{
    public string Discriminator => GetType().Name;

    public string PropB { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IOutput), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

I'm expecting both types `OutputA` and `OutputB` will be listed as return types,
But only `IOutput` is mentioned:

[image]

Alternatively, If I change the `IOutput` from an `interface` to a `class` or an `abstract class` then `OutputA` and `OutputB` will be listed as valid return types:

[image]

Is this not supported due to a RESTFul/API standard?

Or can this be achieved?

This is a `.NET Core 2.2` project, using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v6.2.3`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sharing the solution I found, just in case if someone may need it.

The idea is to add the polymorphic relationships explicitly through the `AddSwaggerGen()` via the `SelectSubTypesUsing()` as:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.UseOneOfForPolymorphism();
    c.SelectSubTypesUsing(baseType =>
    {
        if (baseType == typeof(IOutput))
        {
            return new[]
            {
                typeof(OutputA),
                typeof(OutputB)
            };
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<Type>();
    });
});
```

Comment: we can add SwaggerSubType attribute to the BaseType, so we don't need SelectSubTypesUsing() anymore.

Comment: This feels wrong to me.  Disconnecting the types from the usage.  Why not just add another [ProducesType] to the API definition, then at least it's near where it's used.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the problem of swagger gen not including schema for types that implement an interface (works for abstract base class/record). I used the following solution as it is more generic than specifying individual types.

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(opts => {    
    opts.UseOneOfForPolymorphism();
    //Needed to generate schema from derived types of an interface (base class/record already supported) 
    opts.SelectSubTypesUsing(baseT => {
        return Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(<SomeTypeInTheLibYouwant>))?.GetTypes()
                        .Where(derivedT => baseT.IsAssignableFrom(derivedT));
    });
});
```